# mDNS on OpenBSD; resolving names in the ".local" domain using the standard resolver

Tags: dns, openbsd, mdns

I have a collection of macOS, Ubuntu Linux, and OpenBSD systems. They use mDNS to publish their dynamic IP addresses to the local network, making themselves available under the `.local` domain name.

My OpenBSD 7.1 machines can publish their host information to the LAN using Avahi or [OpenMDNS](http://www.haesbaert.org/openmdns/), and I'm able to connect to them by name from Linux and macOS.  However, the OpenBSD systems cannot resolve the names of neighbouring devices *seamlessly*.

The OpenBSD systems *can* resolve names through the Avahi utilities when they are running Avahi 0.8:

```bsh
$ avahi-resolve-host-name eeyore.local pooh.local laban.local
eeyore.local    192.168.1.127
pooh.local      192.168.1.101
laban.local     192.168.2.100
```

When using OpenMDNS in place of Avahi, I can use its `mdnsctl` command to look up names from OpenBSD:

```bsh
$ mdnsctl lookup pooh.local
Address: 192.168.1.101
```

However, no matter if I use OpenMDNS or Avahi, the normal resolver does not see these names, so I can't, for example, use `ssh`, `ping`, or any other tool to reach them by name from OpenBSD.

I wonder whether one could get OpenBSD's default resolver, or possibly `unwind` or `unbound` in the base system, or some other DNS resolver from packages, to use mDNS as an alternative "forwarder".

Additional info: The local router is an EdgeRouter X from Ubiquiti Inc. (I also have a spare EdgeRouter Lite).  This is what acts as the DHCP and DNS server in the local network.  It forwards DNS queries out of the LAN.  One could enable the `dnsmasq` DHCP+DNS server on the router to provide the hostnames and/or IP addresses from the DHCP leases as responses to DNS queries from the LAN, but this is more of a work-around than a solution to the abovementioned problem (since it does not make the OpenBSD system resolve using mDNS).

Answer (score 0):

You could check - https://github.com/openbsd/src/blob/013e174a3726f5dfc8d86cfb0c801d83d8f77ad6/lib/libc/asr/asr.c#L625

OpenBSD supports only 'file' and 'bind' options in the name resolver (resolv.conf) :-(